# Sudo nautilus command on Kubuntu : critical errors in terminal

Tags: kubuntu, nautilus

I installed `Files` through `Discover` software center on Kubuntu 20.04.1 .
When i use the command `sudo nautilus` in terminal i get critical errors resulting in : `home` folder being empty and `filesystem root` appear different icons of the folder.

My question is if something needs to be installed in Kubuntu so that the command `sudo nautilus` no longer shows errors ?

normal `Files`
[image]

errors
[image]
[image]

terminal errors

```
t@T:~$ sudo nautilus
[sudo] password for t: 

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:4384): WARNING **: 16:12:07.025: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:4384): WARNING **: 16:12:07.029: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4384): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:17:39.291: gtk_widget_get_mapped: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4384): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 16:17:39.291: gdk_window_is_visible: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4384): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 16:17:39.292: gdk_window_show_internal: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4384): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:17:39.292: gtk_widget_set_opacity: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4384): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:17:39.292: gtk_widget_queue_draw: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4384): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:17:41.294: gtk_widget_get_mapped: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4384): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 16:17:41.294: gdk_window_is_visible: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4384): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:17:41.294: gtk_widget_set_opacity: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4384): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:17:41.295: gtk_widget_queue_draw: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
t@T:~$
```

Comment: IIRC `sudo` now defaults to `always_set_home` so you're likely seeing root's `$HOME` (which is `/root` and empty apart from skeleton dotfiles by default)

Comment: When starting GUI apps with `sudo` you should be using `sudo -H`.

Comment: @heynnema `sudo -H nautilus` same problem .

Comment: If you use the standard Kubuntu file manager, everything works ok, correct? Why are you trying to use nautilus?

Comment: I had to delete some files with root permission and `sudo dolphin` doesn't work in kubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema now i did a fresh installation of kubuntu but some time ago i used command `sudo nautilus` in kubuntu and the folder icons looked the same as in `Files`(nautilus) application.

Comment: Deleting files with root ownership/file access, should be done in terminal, not Dolphin or Nautilus... and are you sure that you needed/wanted to delete these files?

Comment: The reason `sudo dolphin` doesn't work is because it's awfully risky to run a file manager as root. Bypassing this with another file manager is not wise. You should learn how to use `rm` from a terminal.